# DateTime function affects original variable when modifying a new variable

Tags: php, datetime

In this script:

```
<?php
$original = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$new = $original;
$new->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $original->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

I expect the `$original` not to be changed. However, the 10 days are indeed also added to this variable. Why is that? It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$new = $original;` just assigns the same reference that's in `$original` to `$new`. Instead you want to make a copy.

```
$new = clone $original;
```